# how do i update a navbar on an api call (specifically a google signin)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i'm having a tough time understanding the hook concept in this case:

the user signs in through google, updating the `session` state.

this updates a `visitorType` state from 'viewer' to 'buyside'...

and then my navbar is supposed to adjust.  but it doesn't, unless switch from the browser to another app and then back again...

```
const { data: session } = useSession(); //next-auth login sessions
const [visitorType, setVisitorType] = useState('viewer')
const visitorRef = useRef(visitorType);

useEffect(()=>{
    return(
      () => {if (session) {
                           visitorRef.current='buyside';
                           setVisitorType('buyside')}
      }
  )
  },[session])
```

from what i understand, useRef gets the value of something between re-rerenders?  and useEffect is asynchronous, so it lags behind? - so, not sure how i can update a reference..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function returned by useEffect fires when the components unmounts. I think what you want is:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if (session) {
    visitorRef.current='buyside';
    setVisitorType('buyside')}
  }
},[session])
```

Regarding your question on useRef:
when you set `visitorRef.current`. No rerender is triggered.

when you call `setVisitorType`, a rerender happens

Comment: i was under the impression that if you have ```result``` in the useEffect function AND a variable in the array, then it becomes a DidUpdate, is that incorrect?

Comment: I didn't get your question. useEffect triggers the first time the component mounts, then it triggers every time a variable in the array passed as second argument changes. and finally the inner function that you return inside the callback you pass to useEffect triggers when the component unmounts https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect